# Raise ValueError from FileNotFoundError, and then do something else

Tags: python, error-handling

When a file is not found, I would like to raise a ValueError with a message (without actually displaying the message), and then do something else.

Attempt:

```
def check_file(file):
    try: 
        #open file here
    except FileNotFoundError: 
        raise ValueError("ValueError message") from None
        #do something else
```

Currently, this outputs `ValueError message`, but I would like to hide it and do something else.

Comment: If you would like to hide it then don't raise the error again. What we usually do is use a [logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) to log such incidents, while not breaking the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
def check_file(file):
    try: 
        #open file here
    except FileNotFoundError: 
        raise ValueError("Caught a FileNotFoundError")
    except ValueError:
        # Catch a ValueError if you want
        raise ValueError("Caught a ValueError")
```

Now when you use it

```
try: 
    check_file(file)
except ValueError as ve: 
    pass
    # Do anything
```

This would print the custom message as well as terminate the program

Comment: is there a way to handle the raised ValueError just like I handled the FileNotFoundError?

Comment: Can I handle the ValueError without actually printing the error "Caught a FileNotFoundError"?

Comment: Just put a ‘pass’ statement.

Comment: It is still printing the exceptions

Comment: Can you post the output?

Comment: You can’t do anything after raising an error. You need to do everything before raising the error. If you want it to do nothing then just catch the exception and say pass if you want nothing to happen after that. The error won’t be printed if it’s caught using except clause.